# How to turn a TIFF file into a binary image in R?

Tags: r, image-processing, binary, tiff

I have a TIFF file, and I need to turn it into a binary image. Is this possible in R? How should I write the arguments for setting a threshold?

Comment: I do not know RMagick, but from the documentation, it seems to me that you could use bilevel_channel with the channel set to all. See bilevel_channel at https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `imager` library's `threshold` function. From the documentation:

```
library(imager)
im <- load.image("cameraman.tif") # provide the correct image path 
im.g <- grayscale(im)
im.g %>% plot
```

[image]

```
threshold(im.g,"15%") %>% plot # the threshold will be set at 15th percentile
```

[image]

```
threshold(im.g,"auto") %>% plot # a threshold will be computed automatically using kmeans
```

[image]

```
#If auto-threshold is too high, adjust downwards or upwards using "adjust"
threshold(im,adjust=1.3) %>% plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [`magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=magick) R package, based on the ImageMagick library:

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.7.4
#> Enabled features: fontconfig, freetype, fftw, lcms, pango, x11
#> Disabled features: cairo, ghostscript, rsvg, webp

logo <- image_read("logo:")

plot(logo)
```

[image]

```r
logo_gray <- image_convert(logo, colorspace = "Gray")

plot(logo_gray)
```

[image]

```r
logo_bw <- logo_gray %>%
  image_threshold(type = "white", threshold = "50%") %>%
  image_threshold(type = "black", threshold = "50%")

plot(logo_bw)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Alternatively, if you want local adaptive thresholding, you should have a look at the `image_lat()` function.